# KafkaStreams Scala: Replace FunctionsCompatConversions

Tags: scala, try-catch, apache-kafka-streams, implicit-conversion

I am using KafkaStreams 2.6.0, scala, in an existing bunch of applications.

I'm devising of a scheme to maximize the uptime/robustness and on every exception, log + (discard or send-to-dead-letter-topic). I want to do this **without** explicitly adding Try/try-catch blocks all over the applications.

I had this idea, to replace `FunctionsCompactConversions` with my own `GuardedFunctionsCompactConversions`, and add Try-s there
e.g.

replace

```
  implicit class ForeachActionFromFunction[K, V](val p: (K, V) => Unit) extends AnyVal {
    def asForeachAction: ForeachAction[K, V] = (key: K, value: V) => p(key, value)
  }
```

with

```
  implicit class ForeachActionFromFunction[K, V](val p: (K, V) => Unit) extends AnyVal {
    def asForeachAction: ForeachAction[K, V] = (key: K, value: V) => {
      setLogContext(value, key)
      Try(p(key, value)) match {
        case Success(_) => 
        case Failure(ex) => Error(s"asForeachAction Failed $ex when handle ($key, $value)")
      }
    }
  }
```

or

```
    def asPredicate: Predicate[K, V] = (key: K, value: V) => p(key, value)
```

with

```
    def asPredicate: Predicate[K, V] = (key: K, value: V) => {
      setLogContext(value, key)
      Try(p(key, value)) match {
        case Success(s) => s
        case Failure(ex) => 
          Error(s"asPredicate Failed $ex when handle ($key, $value)")
          false
      }
    }
```

etc. This way -

1. All the application-provided code is guarded (predicates, reducers, Serde, ...), and one can't "forget" to try/catch
2. Upon any error/exception, can log the message at hand, providing insight as to what the fix should be
3. Centrally able to disable this logging in production etc.
4. Centrally able to opt for the Guarded version if troubleshooting, while using the compact ones by default

Unfortunately I failed to find the right path to do this. I created the `GuardedFunctionsCompactConversions` object, but could not extend/override the compact one, nor get it imported into the proper KTable/KStream/KGroupedStream/... classes.

Is this a common requirement? I expect it is.
Is there a right way to get there?